# The inclusion map is not an embedding?

Tags: differential-topology

[In 4b](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kozai/m141f14/midterm_solutions.pdf) it states:

> Show that the inclusion map is an embedding.

The solution say the question is faulty and proceeds to say

> Using the definition of embedding given by Guillemin and Pollack the inclusion may not be an embedding.

In which case the definition from Guillemin and Pollack is:

> embedding - "An immersion that is injective and proper."

and:

> proper - "if the preimage of every compact set in $Y$ is compact in $X$. Intuitively, a proper map is one that maps points "near infinity" in $X$ to points "near infinity" in $Y$.

My best guess is that the definition of proper can be violated somehow. Mapping points "near infinity" to doesn't necessarily happen. So I guess this would depend on the parameterization of the the manifold. If parameterizations were chosen such that $\phi$ and $\theta$ placed "infinity" in different locations.

For example, consider 4 parameterizations of a circle that cover semicircles. The "standard basis" of such a circumstance includes the top half from $\theta_1 \in (0, \pi)$, left half from $\theta_2 \in (\frac{pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2})$, the bottom half $\theta_3 \in (\pi, 2\pi)$ and the right half from $\theta_4 \in (\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{pi}{2})$. Each parameterization has points just outside of $\theta_i$'s reach. So consider these points to be "infinity".

Choose a different parameterization $\phi_i$ that is $\theta_i$ rotated $45$ degrees. The "infinity" points change and as a results the set isn't (intuitively speaking) *proper* under the inclusion map. So in essence it depends on the parameterization.

I believe this is correct as I don't believe I can take a compact segment of $\theta_i$ where the preimage is not well defined for every parameterization $\phi_i$, and thus the preimage of a compact set is not again compact?

Is this correct? Is my intuition behind this correct?

(Also, note the exam is not from this year it is from **2014**)

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard examples, both of which appear in Guillemin and Pollack. One is the one-to-one immersion of $\Bbb R$ into the plane whose image is a figure eight. The other is given by the mapping $f\colon \Bbb R \to S^1\times S^1$ given by $f(t)=(e^{it},e^{i\alpha t})$, where $\alpha/\pi$ is irrational. In both cases, the image fails to be a submanifold.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand how the inclusion map is used here. For example, in the second example you give, you seem to use $f$ without any mention of an inclusion map.

Comment: Fair enough. I meant the inclusion of the images of these maps. If the domain of the inclusion is in fact a closed submanifold, then of course the map will be an embedding. Also, be careful with what you wrote above. *If* an immersion is one-to-one and proper, then it's an embedding. But the converse needn't hold. Consider the inclusion of an open interval into $\Bbb R$.